# Can't start executable file which uses vtk

Tags: c++, vtk

I have problem starting executable file tutorial on linux, ubuntu 10.10.
I have installed CMake, after that using gui CMake I installed VTK. All was successfully installed using make and make install. I already had installed gnu compiler.

"Project" is written in C++ and is using some basic vtk classes. I successfully compiled the project BUT I have problem starting it. I type in terminal: ./tutorial and nothing happens. I should get cone which will rotate for 360°.

What should I do?

I found [from this link](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~simmerma/vtk_ubuntu.html) something which I didn't do but for the python:

```
export PYTHONPATH=~/VTKBuild/lib/python2.6/site-packages
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:~/VTKBuild/lib/vtk-5.4
```

May this be the problem? and how to create same thing for C++?

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling and running this example:
http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/GeometricObjects/Sphere
and let us know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The guide you suggested is a tad out of date, but with a few tweaks, its very useful. I would run through the 4 minus the python stuff, and it should work.